# RSA: Given (e,c,d) is possible to solve?

Tags: encryption

is it possible to solve RSA without n?

I know **e**, **c** and **d**

Comment: What does "solve RSA" mean?

Comment: I need to decrypt cipher text (C)

Answer (score 5):

No, it would appear to be a hard problem; being able to recover the plaintext allows us to recover $n$ (at least, for small $e$), and recovering $n$ would appear to be difficult.

Knowing $e, d$, we know that $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{ \text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)}$, or equivalently, $ed - 1 = \frac{k}{\text{gcd}(p-1, q-1)} (p-1)(q-1)$, for some integer $k$.

As both $k$ and $\text{gcd}(p-1, q-1)$ are likely to be small (and from $c$, we can get a rough idea about the size of $n$), we are likely to be able to have a plausible guess to $(p-1)(q-1)$.

However, to convert that to $pq$, we'll need to factor $(p-1)(q-1)$; while $p-1, q-1$ both a likely to have some small factors (allowing us to reduce the size of the problem a bit), however, it appears likely that there won't be enough small factors to reduce the size enough; performing a complete factorization won't be all that much easier than the original 'factor $pq$' problem...

Answer (score 1):

Alice can recover *m* from *c* by using her private key exponent *d* by computing

[image: RSA Decryption]

Given *m*, she can recover the original message *M* by reversing the padding scheme.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)#Decryption

Comment: Please note that the OP's question was if and how they can do this _without knowing $n$_.

Comment: Yes. I understand. I think the above quote from wiki has the answer.

Comment: How is one supposed to compute the $\bmod n$ to recover $m$ if one doesn't know $n$?

Comment: You see? That is exactly the point.

Comment: The $(\text{ mod } n)$ is not notation that it is implicitly done (which the parentheses may suggest to you), $n$ most be known to perform the modular exponentiation.